# Vector comprehension in R - paste function

Tags: string, r, list, list-comprehension

Is there a way in R to write vector comprehension using the paste function?
I simply need to get a **one string representation of a (long) vector (*data*)**, like this:

```
data = [1, 58, 120]
s = paste(data[1], data[2], data[3], sep=", ")
```

Isn't there a nicer solution than do this in a for-loop?

I found this about comprehensions in R:
[List comprehension in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998716/list-comprehension-in-r#)
but it does not seem to work with paste.

Comment: `data <- c(1, 2, 3)`;`paste(data, collapse = ", ")`

Comment: In R, the element defined with `[]` is called a vector, not a list. Please edit your question title.

Comment: @cafe876 There's no such constructor (`[`) in R to build a `vector`

Comment: What exactly do you want to do here? Construct a character string representation of your vector `s`? Or create a vector using a list comprehension syntax?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I edited the question to make it clear. I want to have a one-string representation of the vector data, s should be the result.

Answer (score 1):

Like @dickoa already commented, reducing a vector `s` into one string separated by `,` you can use `paste`:

```
data <- c(1, 2, 3)
paste(data, collapse = ", ")
```