# List comprehension in R: map, not filter

Tags: r, performance, list-comprehension, vectorization, idioms

So, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998716/list-comprehension-in-r) tells how to perform a list comprehension in R to filter out new values.

I'm wondering, what is the standard R way of writing a list comprehension which is generating new values?

Basically, if we have a function `f`and vector `x`, I want the list `f(el) for el in x`. (This is like map in functional programming).

In Python, this would just be `[f(el) for el in x]`. How do I write this in R, in the standard way?

The problem is, right now I have for-loops:

```
result = c(0)
for (i in 1:length(x))
{
    result[i] = f(x[i])
}
```

Is there a more R-like way to write this code, to avoid the overhead of for-loops?

Comment: you're looking for `lapply` or `sapply`.

Comment: There is a chance, also, that `f` operates on a vector input; `x = 1:10; sapply(x, function(X) X + 2); x + 2`. BTW, your "result", also, could have been initialized with the known size: `rep(0, length(x))`

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend taking a look at the R package [rlist](http://renkun.me/rlist/) which provides a number of utility functions that make it very easy to work with lists. For example, you could write

```
list.map(x, x ~ x + f(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Following works without any special functions:

```
> x <- 1:10
> f <- function(x) {x+log(x)}
> 
> f(x)
 [1]  1.000000  2.693147  4.098612  5.386294  6.609438  7.791759  8.945910 10.079442 11.197225 12.302585

> result = f(x)
> result
 [1]  1.000000  2.693147  4.098612  5.386294  6.609438  7.791759  8.945910 10.079442 11.197225 12.302585
```

If x is a vector, result of f(x) will be a vector.

```
> y = 12
> f(y)
[1] 14.48491
```